# same capacity external HDD,but different price

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

i am going to buy 1TB external HDD manufactured by western digital.I have found two of them in the shop's website.Both of them have 1TB capacity,but one is almost 13-14$ more than the other.Models are:

1. Model  WDBZFP0010BBLUltra ->83$(approximately) and
2. Model  WDBUZG0010BBK-BESN ->71$(approximately)

**Specifications for two models  found  in the local shop's website are:**

specification for the first one is :

```
 Brand  Western Digital
Model   WDBZFP0010BBLUltra
Storage     1 TB
Type    SATA External
Buffer  8 MB
Interface   USB 2.0/ 3.0
Transfer Rate   USB 3.0: Up to 5Gbps; USB 2.0: Up to 480Mbps
Warranty    3 Year
Short Description   

Western Digital My Passport WDBZFP0010BBLUltra 1TB Blue USB.3.0 HDD
Long Description    

Brand - Western Digital, Model - Western Digital My Passport WDBZFP0010BBLUltra, Storage - 1TB, Type - SATA External, RPM - 5400, Buffer (MB) - 8, Interface - USB 2.0/ 3.0, Transfer Rate (MB/s) - USB 2.0 up to 480 Mb/s; USB 3.0 up to 5Gb/s, Color - Blue, Warranty - 3 Years Warranty
Product ID  102.170.46
```

and for the second one :

```
Brand  Western Digital
Model  WDBUZG0010BBK-BESN
Storage  1 TB
Type  SATA External
RPM  WDBUZG0010BBK-BESN
Buffer  8MB
From Factor  N/A
Interface  USB 3.0
Transfer Rate  N/A
```

why there is a price difference between the two?? .Which one will be better??If both of them are the same i will definenately go for the lower price model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WDBZFP0010BBLUltra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EAS8KSW) has a three year warranty, whereas the other has a [1-year warranty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CI3BLPA). WD issues longer warranties on their better quality disks (caviar blacks and their enterprise lines are 5-year), so it is an indication that they have more confidence in the disk in the enclosure.

Personally I always buy Black-line drives and a separate enclosure, because they tend to use cheaper disks (Blue-line or worse) in the pre-packaged externals, but thats just my preference. I would however recommend getting the best drive you can for the money. so the Ultra disk appears by far to be the better choice.

Comment: thanks !! what do you mean by black line drives..? did you indicate to the second model with this??

Comment: Western Digital has a number of product lines for differant evironments and needs. The Caviar Black line of drives are their top line for consumer end disks, and carry a 5-year warranty. No, neither of the disks you indicate are Black line, though the Ultra is a Caviar Blue line drive, which is for standard business computing, where a 3-year warranty is generally sufficient. I would not tryst the disk with the 1-year warranty at all.

Comment: i have one thing to ask,from their site for blue line i found this recommendation -" WD Blue storage is tested and recommended for use in desktop and All-in-One PCs, industrial applications, notebooks, and external enclosures where capacity is not needed. For additional capacity, look at WD Green capacity storage drives" ----->i want to use it to store data for a longer period of time like videos and other files.will it be sufficient for my purpose??

Comment: Probably, but with any hard disk, you need to make sure that the SMART health stats are good every few months and that the filesystem itself is well maintained (chkdsk) if you wish to keep data for long periods of time. Thats why I always go for the longest warranty possible, as the manufacturer has the most faith in those products.